# Adding events to a class using +=

Tags: c#, eventhandler

Please forgive my little knowledge!

I have the following class in HIDNewDeviceEventMonitor.cs:

```
public class HIDNewDeviceEventMonitor : IDisposable
{
    // used for monitoring plugging and unplugging of USB devices.
    private ManagementEventWatcher watcherAttach;

    public HIDNewDeviceEventMonitor()
    {
        // Catch USB HID plugged instance event watching
        watcherAttach = new ManagementEventWatcher();
        watcherAttach.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
        watcherAttach.Query = new WqlEventQuery(@"SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PNPEntity' AND TargetInstance.DeviceID LIKE 'HID\\VID_04D8%'");
        watcherAttach.Start();
    }

    void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("my device is inserted..");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        watcherAttach.Stop();
        watcherAttach.Dispose();
    }

    ~HIDNewDeviceEventMonitor()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now, how can I change this class to be able to add an event handler that the class can  call from within watcher_EventArrived where someNewEvent is outside the class file, actually in the form.cs:

```
// code in the form
HIDNewDeviceEventMonitor ok = new HIDNewDeviceEventMonitor();
ok.Inserted += someNewEvent;  // <-- my problem, I don't know how to add an event to the class this way

private void someNewEvent()
{
    //Enumerate and add to listbox1
}
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    ok.Dispose();
}
```

I 've seen this thing with other classes, how can I make my class like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add an event to a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85137/how-to-add-an-event-to-a-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you're trying to add events to your `HIDNewDeviceMonitor` class.

To do this, first you'll need to define a delegate.

```
public delegate void InsertedHandler;
```

Next, you'll need to define the event in your `HIDNewDeviceMonitor` class.

```
// Notice how the event uses the delegate that's been defined
//               v       
public event InsertedHandler Inserted;
```

Now you'll need something that "fires" the event, which could easily be put in your `watcher_EventArrived` method.

```
void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("my device is inserted..");

    // Notice how we check the event handler for null.
    // If you don't, it could throw a NullReferenceException.
    // Irritating, but easy to debug.. Usually..
    if (Inserted != null)
        Inserted(); // Or whatever parameters you need.
}
```

We're all done with the `HIDNewDeviceMonitor` class.

Now whatever class that uses the `HIDNewDeviceMonitor` can use the EventHandler code that you provided.

However, it'll have to be the same delegate.

```
public class MyClass
{
  HIDNewDeviceMonitor monitor;
  public MyClass()
  {
    monitor = new HIDNewDeviceMonitor();
    monitor.Inserted += DeviceInserted;
  } 

  private void DeviceInserted() 
  { 
   // Execute code here
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but why do you want to create MyClass? I just want to `HIDNewDeviceEventMonitor ok = new HIDNewDeviceEventMonitor();` and be able to `ok.Insterted += someNewEvent;` strange that I have to wrap this inside a new class

Comment: BTW, if I use ok.Inserted, the IDE complains saying that ok is a field, not a type!

Comment: @elekgeek I added that `MyClass` as an example for something that's encapsulating the `HIDNewDeviceEventMonitor`. I assuming that you'll be using a WinForms Form to do the same.

Comment: @elekgeek After looking at your provided code, you'll need to add your EventHandler subscription (aka `ok.Inserted += someNewEvent;`) within the constructor of your Form1. (It should be notated as `public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); // Maybe other code here }`)

Comment: I got your point, `public Form1()` :- ) It works now, thanks for pointing out, I did not read your last comment till after i figured this my self, but really thanks for pointing it out :- )

Answer (score 2):

Your `Inserted` event should look like this:

```
public event EventHandler Inserted;
```

You invoke it like this:

```
private void OnInserted()
{
    if (this.Inserted != null)
    {
        this.Inserted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

The signature for the event handler is this:

```
void someNewEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
}
```

Then you should wrap that code in the constructor of the class:

```
HIDNewDeviceEventMonitor ok;

public ClassName()
{
   ok = new HIDNewDeviceEventMonitor();
   ok.Inserted += someNewEvent;  // <-- my problem
}
```

Declare the `ok` variable outside the constructor, and instantiate it inside. Then add the event handler.

**Pro tip:** You could use the generic [`EventHandler<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you need to supply a custom implementation of `e`.

Comment: I think that's his question; how to create the `Inserted` event

Comment: I stated that this is my problem, I don't know how to correctly create an event inside the class that can be assigned to an instance of this class in this manner i.e. =+ because I want to hide watcher_EventArrived and still be able to call another event from it.

Comment: You forgot to mention how to invoke the event from `watcher_EventArrived` ;)

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman Why would I do that, for example, in "Windows Form Designer generated code" I can see that it is possible to write: `this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);` if I follow your answer, this aint right to be honest

Comment: @Patrick Hofman, I just want to add an event handler to my class, the event handler doesn't take any arguments, and call this event handler from within watcher_EventArrived, to do other tasks. I don't want to supply any arguments, nor I want to wrap the declaration in a new class..

Comment: @elekgeek There's multiple ways to define events. `button1.Click = ButtonClicked;` is equivalent to `button1.Click = new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonClicked);`. The designer just chooses to write it that way. Needlessly wordy, but pointless to go back and correct.

Comment: I don't see a new class, and an `EventHandler` has a specific signature. If you don't want that, use an `Action` and assign with `=`.

Comment: I mean public ClassName()

Comment: @elekgeek: That is just the constructor from a class in your existing code, but  I don't know the name of it (`in the form.cs`). You put code in the class where you had to add it to the constructor.

Comment: What I am trying to say that if I do this as you say, the IDE complains that ok is a field and not a type, so I can't use ok.Inserted..

Comment: @elekgeek: Not inside your class definition, yes, put it in a method.

Comment: I got your point, `public Form1()`     :- )   It works now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following in the HIDNewDeviceEventMonitor class:

1.) First define a public event inside the class like this-

`public event EventHandler Inserted;`

2.) Then fire this event within the code where you detect the changes in events. Like this-

`if(Inserted != null)
        Inserted(this,null);`

The if condition checks if the event is registered by any listener. It's fired in case it is.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Once I write ok.Inserted, the IDE complains about ok being a field, not a type.. my problem is that Inserted is not recognized as a member event of ok